# Animate.css and fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I have simple markup like http://jsfiddle.net/2nzp8835/1/. After clicking on `expand` content becomes "full screened". Then I added fade in animation using animate.css like on http://jsfiddle.net/ph1rvh6p/1/ and `expand` was stop working.
 I can't figure out why. Is it possible to use both animate.css with fixed positioned elements?

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome 37, however it seems to work fine in IE11, browser bug maybe?

Comment: For me it is not working in FF and Chrome, IE10,11 are good.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it, but there is some reason that I can't still figure it out.
My solution is here: [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2nzp8835/3/)

The key attribute is `vw` and `vh`

```
.fullscreen-mode{
    height: 100vh;
    left: -10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

it's CSS3 attribute. If you consider IE8~IE9, It's may be ineffective. But on Chrome and FF, it works well.
I try it to find the detail reason.
Here is some clue:
**In the animation.css**, you used these class

```
    .fadeInRight {
        animation-name: fadeInRight;
    }
    .animated {
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
```

I remove some of these. And the effective will be back. So, I guess the **animtion** redefine the page flow so that make your purpose effect doesn't work.

---

Here is a attach question:
**How the class named *animated* and .*fadeInRight* effects page flow in animation.css?**
Hope someone can help.

Comment: It's expanded, but under the .head element. I suppose that it should be "full screened"

Comment: @Kai About expanded just modify the value of `vh` and `vw` to match your page. Change the value of  `left` and `top` to **0**.It will be as same as your first verison. Like this. http://jsfiddle.net/2nzp8835/4/

Comment: In your answer content is not animated. Try to add animation and expand will stop working

Comment: @Kai I failed to achieve, maybe you can make it use jQuery `animate`, in addition, I think animation.css is better used on first page load. In other word, change DOM to get effect maybe isn't fit for animation.css.